# Laravel DI coupling differences

Tags: php, laravel, dependency-injection, coupling

What is the difference in class coupling if you use these 3 types of usages:

**Case 1**

```
use UserRepository

...

UserRepository::getUser();
```

**Case 2**

```
App::make('UserRepository')->getUser();
```

**Case 3**

```
public function __construct(UserRepository $userRepository)
{
    $this->userRepository = $userRepository;
}
...
$this->userRepository->getUser();
```

Is there any reason to prefer one over the other?

**EDIT**

I feel as though the constructor option is the best way to go, but I find myself in question when I need to include 3 services and 3 repositories in the controller which then very soon escalates to 6 parameters in constructor.

**EDIT - Case 4**

What about when you're using a facade instead?

**EDIT - Case 5**

What about when you specify it as `\UserRepository`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, the idea of the Repository is to have an Interface (UserRepositoryInterface) and classes that implement it (MySQLUserRepository, RedisUserRepository). It gives you a quick way to change the storage of users through your DI container by calling an interface:

```
public function __construct(UserRepositoryInterface $userRepository)
{
    $this->userRepository = $userRepository;
}
```

And changing it to any implementation in the DI container.

Let's say you have a Controller with 10 actions.

**Case 1** Is not the OOP way, because the call doesn't go through the DI container at all.

**Case 2** is actually OK, but you'll have to call the App facade in every action. It's not really beautiful.

**Case 3** gives you only one place to create/change/configure the class.

E.g. you need to do something like:

```
public function __construct(UserRepository $userRepository)
{
    $this->userRepository = $userRepository;
    $this->userRepository->excludeAdmins();
}
```

A lot of repositories in constructor is actually ok, however if the code fills gross to you, you can extract it to a Service class.

**UPDATE**
By Service class I mean a class that doesn't extends anything and contains the business logic.

Further reading: https://m.dotdev.co/design-pattern-service-layer-with-laravel-5-740ff0a7b65f

**Case 4**. Facades, in my opinion, are suitable for something more global. Why would you want to populate each repository with a facade? Too time consuming.

**Case 5**. Didn't get the question. You mean put it to the root namespace? What does it change?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by extracting to Service class?

Comment: Also, I have updated my question, so if you could give additional info I'd be grateful

Comment: Updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks. Yeah, I meant root namespace, don't know how it functions under the hood